Taking the derivative with respect to a function of x but slightly more complicated
Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be continuous functions of $x$, how would you find $$\frac{d}{dg(x)}\bigg(\frac{df(x)}{dx}\bigg)$$ just in terms of $x, f(x), g(x)$ and derivates with respect to $x$, so $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$? If this isn't possible in general without knowing the functions, as an example, what if trying to find $$\frac{d}{log(x)}\bigg(\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg)$$ where $y$ depends on $x$ in some way. Obviously here one function is known and swapping the order of differentiation is not allowed. Is it possible to write this in terms of $x, \frac{dy}{dx}$ and $log(x)$ though I doubt the solution would include $log(x)$?
Yes I realise it's just $f''(x)/g'(x)$ subject to non-zero conditions and I was being slow.

Adopt the fundamental principle that you can only take the derivative of a function with respect to a variable it depends on. $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ is an OK function of $x,.$ Call it $h(x),.$ When can we say that $h$ depends on $g(x),?$  Hint: asking when $h$ depends on $g$ might be simpler. Hint II: which function must be invertible?

Cheers for the reply

That expression can be given a meaning if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable and $g'$ is nonzero. In that case it's simply the quotient of the two derivatives. In the concrete case of the natural logarithm this would give a requirement for $x$ to be positive and then the result is $x.y'$

Yeah I realised as soon as I posted it that it's no different to $df(x)/dg(x)$ as it's still just a function of $x$, cheers for the reply though

$$
\frac{df}{dx}(x)=f'(x)=:h(x)
$$
is a function of $x$ that we wish to differentiate w.r.t. $g\,.$ When
$x\mapsto g(x)$ is invertible (and differentiable) this is no problem: by the chain rule, and the inverse function theorem
$$
\frac{d}{dg}h(x(g))=h'(x(g))\frac{dx}{dg}(g)=\frac{h'(x(g))}{g'(x(g))}=\frac{f''(x(g))}{g'(x(g))}\,.\tag1
$$

Regarding the notation $\frac{dh(g(x))}{dg(x)}\,:$ I think this is pretty confusing. Does it mean $\frac{dh(y)}{dy}$ with $y=g(x)\,?$ If so the equation (1) becomes
$$
h'(y)=h'(x(g))\,.\tag2
$$ I recommend to avoid $\frac{dh(g(x))}{dg(x)}$ or say exactly what it means.

